# Autocomplete does not work in XML files in particular hierarchy

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, eclipse-adt, drawerlayout

In particular XML nodes hierarchy eg. DrawerLayout->RelativeLayout->ImageButton autocomplete does not work as expected. Suggestion list contains invalid items. Eg. `android:src` is not shown inside `ImageButton` while it should be.

Invalid proposals:
[image: ok]

On the other hand if hierarchy is RelativeLayout->RelativeLayout->ImageButton then everything is OK.

Valid proposals:
[image: not ok]

I've already tried:

- reopening XML file - no effect
- reopening project - no effect
- restarting eclipse - no effect

Comment: The two screenshots look the same to me.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Screenshots corrected.

Comment: I sometimes don`t get any proposals at all. guess it`s a bug. reopen your xml file, and it should work again..

Comment: I've already tried this as well as reopening a project and restarting eclipse. None of them works.

Answer (score 2):

If inner RelativeLayout is moved to another XML file and included via `<include layout="@layout/inner"/>` then autocomplete is working. But it is a dirty workaround, not a real solution. So I am not accepting this answer.