# Eclipse Content Assist Not Working Properly For Android Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

Whenever I have Views inside a `ViewGroup` inside a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`, Eclipse's autocomplete starts working weird. It doesn't display most of the properties

Example with DrawerLayout -> LinearLayout -> ImageView:

[image: Autocomplete not working]

In the previous screenshot, you can see that I typed "`android:scale`..." and the IDE's intellisense isn't showing me the ImageView's `android:scaleType`

If I use Eclipse's Properties window for the `ImageView`, I can see that it is only displaying the basic properties for "`View`" (and not for `ImageView`...):

[image: Eclipse Property Window]

Now if the ImageView is not a descendant of the DrawerLayout and I put it somewhere else, the autocomplete works properly:

[image: Now It Works...]

I've seen related questions such as:

- [Autocomplete does not work in XML files in particular hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135044/autocomplete-does-not-work-in-xml-files-in-particular-hierarchy)
- [Content Assist doesn't work in xml with support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380553/content-assist-doesnt-work-in-xml-with-support-library)

but they have been dead with no answers for quite a while...

Content assist doesn't work for Views (be it TextViews, EditText, Buttons...) that I add inside the DrawerLayout. It only suggests the 'basic' properties.

Does anybody know why this happens or how to fix this?

## Sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/some_image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: When using support package Widgets this is a common scenario - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537733/no-layout-width-attribute-shown-in-option-list-when-using-drawerlayout-in-adt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give some closure to this 5 months-old question, I'll quote and [link to Atul O Holic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537733/no-layout-width-attribute-shown-in-option-list-when-using-drawerlayout-in-adt). Thanks to Dileep Perla for pointing me there.

> When using support package Widgets this is a common scenario (a weird
>   one too).
>
> Here you using, `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` and hence the
>   issue. Happened with me a lot of time.
>
> You can also try couple of options mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the  tag can be handy in this case. Just put your layout that is inside the drawer in a separate layout file and then include it inside the drawer layout.